# Autofill password for openssl

Tags: openssl

I have encrypted my shell script with openssl. Now i am using it with decrytion like

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in encryptedshell.sh |sh -
```

After running this command system asks for password.Now I am trying to autofill  password by EOF like

```
pass=abc
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in encryptedshell.sh |sh -  <<EOF 
pass $pass
```

Whether it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in encrypted-shell.sh -pass pass:mypassword |sh -
```

Comment: This appears to be the same command that you mentioned in the question, how does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `yes` utility. You can use like this:

```
$ yes [your-password] | openssl-command
```

Best regards.